# Angular 8 Error :content_script.js:71 LEVEL: ERROR | MODULE: LEAKED_CREDENTIAL

Tags: angular, npm

I Currently have a angular 8 application with dotnet core,

and recently I started seeing the following error appearing in the developers console:

content_script.js:71 LEVEL: ERROR | MODULE: LEAKED_CREDENTIALS | SESSION: a1293cfe | MESSAGE: "CryptoJS.SHA256 is not a function" | PARAMS: {}

How do I fix this error, as I don't use this CryptoJS.SHA256 function anywhere in my code or cryptoJS for that matter?

And this seems to happen every time the route of the app changes.

what my routes look like in my app.module file:

```
 RouterModule.forRoot([{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ pathMatch: 'full', path: 'admin-dash', component: AdmindashboardComponent },
{ pathMatch: 'full', path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent },
  { pathMatch: 'full', path: 'user-registration', component: UserRegistrationComponent },
  { pathMatch: 'full', path: 'settings', component: SettingComponent },
  { pathMatch: 'full', path: 'healthplan', component: HealthplanComponent },
  {
    pathMatch: 'full', path: 'registeredusers', component: RegisteredusersComponent
  },
  { pathMatch: 'full', path: 'manual-grid', component: ManualsComponent },
  {
    pathMatch: 'full', path: 'restore-claims', component: RestoreclaimsComponent
  },
  {
    pathMatch: 'full', path: 'User-Rights', component: UserRightsComponent
  }])
```

And the code I use to route for example when the user successfully logs in:

```
router.navigateByUrl('/login')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not be importing the CryptoJS directly - but it's most possibly a dependency of one of the packages that you're using (e.g. added them in package.json). Try running [npm ls](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls.html). It allows you to generate the dependency tree of your packages. It also allows looking for a single package in such a tree, e.g.

```
npm ls CryptoJS
```

should generate a tree in which CryptJS is used. Then, you can pinpoint the issue and either fix or it contact the package author.

Comment: Thank you, I ran the command and got the following result : `-- (empty), does this mean nothing uses CryptoJs?

Comment: So, the npm package that's imported as CryptoJS is most probably called "crypto-js" so try running `npm ls crypto-js`

Comment: And if it's not in the results - it might be one of the browser extensions causing the issue. Try running it on other, "clean" browser (e.g. no extensions, addons, etc.) Sometimes those can cause similar issues as well.

Comment: Thanks, the following package came up with the crypto-js command:oidc-client@1.10.1, i will do a test on a browser with no extensions, as our antivirus adds an extensions which was giving problems with iis a while ago.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Remember to mark the question as answered (if that's correct solution) so it doesn't pop in 'unanswered' filters.